# What does an interface for passing multiple data-types as parameters to a method look like?

Tags: java, android, interface, abstract-class

I am a Java noob, and tried to find the answer to the following, but wasn't able to identify the correct interface for the following problem. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

I have the following piece of reusable code in Android Studio:

```
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsGenerator() {

    //convert pixels to dpi
    int pixelHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int pixelWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    // Sets LayoutParams
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(pixelHeight, pixelWidth);

    //ensure placed button is placed in centre
    int xButton = addTaskButton.getLeft();
    int yButton = addTaskButton.getTop();

    //defines the LayoutParameters we will a sssign to the button we created above
    layoutParams.leftMargin = xButton;
    layoutParams.topMargin = yButton;

    return layoutParams;
}
```

The code reads the layout parameters of the "addTaskButton" and returns it.

I now want to make this method applicable to any View Object, not jut the 'addTaskButton' that is currently hard-coded in the code above (i.e. Image Views, text views etc.). I am aware that this requires the implementation of an interface as per the following [Java: Passing multiple parameters to a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842584/java-passing-multiple-parameters-to-a-method) but I can't seem to get the implementation right.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Z

Answer (score 1):

All view types inherit from `View` class so passing `View view` as method argument and replace button by the `view` should resolve your problem.